# How to customize links in TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

I'm using links in my Android Studio project activity via `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`.

By default links are color of AppTheme's Accent color and have a bottom line (underline). So how to customize links in TextView: remove underlining, change color and text style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `android:textColorLink` attribute to change the text color.

Comment: I cannot find the source but I guess it comes from the `Html.fromHtml()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own custom styles and then apply them to your textview in the layout xml file.

```
<TextView
   style="@style/CodeFont"
   android:text="@string/hello" />
```

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html for more details.

Comment: I know that, but I mean how to customize exactly links inside the TextView.